# How to use action delegate to avoid if else

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have the following code:

```
public class NotificationService {
    private readonly Dictionary<NotificationMessageType, Action<IList<RecipientDetail>, NotificationMessageType>> _actionMap;
    public NotificationService() [
        _actionMap = new Dictionary<NotificationMessageType, Action<IList<RecipientDetail>, NotificationMessageType>> ();
        _actionMap.Add(NotificationMessageType.SessionBookedReminder, new Action<IList<RecipientDetail>, NotificationMessageType>(GenerateNotificationsAsync)); //getting errror here because of async await
    }
    public async Task GenerateNotificationsAsync(IList<RecipientDetail> usersToNotify, NotificationMessageType messageType)
    {
```

Would like to avoid if else here:

```
        if(messageType == NotificationMessageType.SessionBookedReminder)
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(usersToNotify.Select(u => GenerateBookingNotificationAsync(u, messageType)).ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(usersToNotify.Select(u => SendNotificationAsync(u, messageType)).ToArray());
        }
    }

    public async Task GenerateNotificationsAsync(IList<RecipientDetail> usersToNotify, NotificationMessageType messageType)
    {
    }

    public async Task GenerateBookingNotificationAsync(RecipientDetail userToNotify, NotificationMessageType messageType)
    { 
    }

}
```

How can I use action delegate to avoid if else. I've tried with following, but getting error due to async await.

Can anyone help how to do the right way?

Thanks

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(usersToNotify.Select(u => messageType 
 == NotificationMessageType.SessionBookedReminder ? GenerateBookingNotificationAsync(u, messageType) : SendNotificationAsync(u, messageType)).ToArray());` do you really need a delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary must match the method declaration, your methods returns a task, so your

```
Action<IList<RecipientDetail>, NotificationMessageType>
```

Must be changed to something like

```
Func<IList<RecipientDetail>, NotificationMessageType,Task>
```

your method must return a task in order to use it in a async/await manner

Comment: thanks. instead of using func with return as Task, is there a way to use async await inside Action delegate?

Comment: Why, what would be the purpose? If your program is async it should be async all the way, an action that does not return a Task will not be async it self, and thus stop the async 'chain'

Comment: If you want to use await Task.WhenAll(.....) then you must somehow provide a collection of tasks to put inside WhenAll. If the input comes from your dictionary then it must either return a task, or be a Action that you wrap in another method that returns a Task